# How to close NerdTree Menu?

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

I use Vim plugin NerdTree. If I have to quickly add a file, the NerdTreeMenu I get by pressing `m` is very helful.

How I can close my `NerdTreeMenu`? I'm unable to find information in any documentation on closing the NerdTree menu.

Comment: https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/issues/1321

Answer (score 2):

It is either `:NERDTreeClose` to close it, or `:NERDTreeToggle` to toggle it **on** and **off** :)

Edit: [@Gustav Blomqvist](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/2689/gustav-blomqvist) reminded me, that you can also use the classic vim exit commands while the **NERDTree** window is in **focus**:

- `:q`
- `ZZ` 2x(Shift + z)
- `^Wq` (Ctrl-w + q)

Comment: `:q` in the NERDTree window also works. :)

A tip is to bind `:NERDTreeToggle`
Ctrl+n to toggle NERDTree
`nnoremap <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>`

Comment: Yeah right you could also do it that way. You can also use the classic vim exit commands (:q  /  ZZ  /  ^Wq) I will write that to my answer, thanks :))

Comment: OP is not asking how to close the NerdTree window.

Answer (score 0):

If the NERDTree window is in focus then just a simple `q` will work.

Comment: OP is not asking how to close the NerdTree window.

Comment: Oh my bad `Ctrl-c` closes the `NERDTreeMenu`